# Рамка вокруг div углом - как здесь

Tags: jquery, css

[image: при наведении на пункт меню чтобы всплывала рамка как на картинке]

при наведении на пункт меню нужно чтобы всплывало такое меню - рамка чтобы была углом вокруг div.

Comment: есть примемер кода...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Например так:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #fff;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  position: relative;  
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.list {
  border: 1px solid limegreen;
  border-radius: 4px;
  max-width: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

.sub {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  left: 90%;
  background: #fff;
  top: -1px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 150px;
  display: none;
}

.sub li:hover {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

li:hover a {
  z-index: 7;
}

li:hover {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  border-right:  1px solid #fff;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 5;
}

li:hover .sub {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>
    <a href="#">item 1</a>
    
    <ul class="sub">
      <li><a href="">item 2.1</a>  </li>
      <li><a href="">item 2.2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">item 2.3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">item 2</a>
    
    <ul class="sub">
      <li><a href="">item 2.1</a>  </li>
      <li><a href="">item 2.2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">item 2.3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">item 3</a>
    
    <ul class="sub">
      <li><a href="">item 3.1</a>  </li>
      <li><a href="">item 3.2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">item 3.3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Попробовал локально--это работает, спасибо Вам умная и очень красивая девушка Елена.

Comment: Лена - 300р на телефон переведу - помоги пожалуйста рамку эту сделать по тимвьюеру? Skype poluusver

Comment: По тимвьюверу не получится, может быть ссылка есть?

Answer (score 1):

Для бокового меню:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.submenu {
  display: none;
}

.menu {
  width: 200px;
  border-left: 2px solid #000000;
  border-right: 2px solid #000000;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 20px;
}

.item {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
}

.item:hover {
  border: 3px solid #00ffe5;
  border-right: none;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item:hover::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -3px;
  bottom: -3px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #00ffe5;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
}

.item:hover::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 9px;
  bottom: -13px;
  border: 3px solid #00ffe5;
  border-left: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  width: 90px;
  height: 10px;
}

.submenu > li {
  padding: 10px;
}

.item:hover .submenu {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: 180px;
  width: 200px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  border: 3px solid #00ffe5;
  border-left: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.submenu::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 65px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 5px;
  right: 0;
  border: 3px solid #00ffe5;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="item">
    1 ПУНКТ МЕНЮ
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li>1.1 ПОДПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
      <li>1.2 ПОДПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
      <li>1.3 ПОДПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    2 ПУНКТ МЕНЮ
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li>2.1 ПОДПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
      <li>2.2 ПОДПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
      <li>2.3 ПОДПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
      <li>2.4 ПОДПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    3 ПУНКТ МЕНЮ
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li>3.1 ПОДПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
      <li>3.2 ПОДПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    4 ПУНКТ МЕНЮ
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li>4.1 ПОДПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
      <li>4.2 ПОДПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
      <li>4.3 ПОДПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
      <li>4.4 ПОДПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
      <li>4.5 ПОДПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
      <li>4.6 ПОДПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    5 ПУНКТ МЕНЮ
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li>5.1 ПОДПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
      <li>5.2 ПОДПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
      <li>5.3 ПОДПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
      <li>5.4 ПОДПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
      <li>5.5 ПОДПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
      <li>5.3 ПОДПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Для блоков:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 900px;
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  /*flex-grow: 1;*/
  margin: 0 10px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  line-height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #00ffe5;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.item:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.menu {
  display: none;
  height: 150px;
}

.item:hover > .menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 140px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #00ffe5;
  border-top: 3px solid transparent;
  border-left: 3px solid transparent;
  border-right: 3px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu > li {
    display: block;
    width: 25%;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.block1:hover::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 143px;
    bottom: -20px;
    left: 253px;
    right: 30px;
    border: 3px solid #00ffe5;
    border-top: 3px solid transparent;
    border-right: 3px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

.block1:hover > .menu::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    border: 3px solid #00ffe5;
    top: -20px;
    bottom: -3px;
    left: -3px;
    width: 20px;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

.block1:hover > .menu::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    border: 3px solid #00ffe5;
    top: 20px;
    bottom: -3px;
    right: -3px;
    width: 40px;
    border-left: none;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

.block2:hover::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 143px;
    bottom: -20px;
    left: 30px;
    right: 570px;
    border: 3px solid #00ffe5;
    border-top: 3px solid transparent;
    border-left: 3px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

.block2:hover::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 143px;
    bottom: -20px;
    left: 570px;
    right: 30px;
    border: 3px solid #00ffe5;
    border-top: 3px solid transparent;
    border-right: 3px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;us: 10px;
}

.block2:hover > .menu::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    border: 3px solid #00ffe5;
    top: 20px;
    bottom: -3px;
    left: -3px;
    width: 20px;
    border-right: none;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

.block2:hover > .menu::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    border: 3px solid #00ffe5;
    top: 20px;
    bottom: -3px;
    right: -3px;
    width: 40px;
    border-left: none;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

.block3:hover::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 143px;
    bottom: -20px;
    left: 30px;
    right: 253px;
    border: 3px solid #00ffe5;
    border-top: 3px solid transparent;
    border-left: 3px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

.block3:hover > .menu::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    border: 3px solid #00ffe5;
    top: 20px;
    bottom: -3px;
    left: -3px;
    width: 20px;
    border-right: none;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

.block3:hover > .menu::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    border: 3px solid #00ffe5;
    top: -20px;
    bottom: -3px;
    right: -3px;
    width: 40px;
    border-left: none;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul class="wrapper">
            <li class="item block1">
              БЛОК 1
              <ul class="menu">
                <li>01 ПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
                <li>02 ПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
                <li>03 ПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
                <li>04 ПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
                <li>05 ПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
                <li>06 ПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
                <li>07 ПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
                <li>08 ПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
                <li>09 ПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
                <li>10 ПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
                <li>11 ПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
                <li>12 ПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="item block2">
              БЛОК 2
              <ul class="menu">
                <li>01 ПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
                <li>02 ПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
                <li>03 ПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
                <li>04 ПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
                <li>05 ПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
                <li>06 ПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
                <li>07 ПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
                <li>08 ПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
                <li>09 ПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="item block3">
              БЛОК 3
              <ul class="menu">
                <li>01 ПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
                <li>02 ПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
                <li>03 ПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
                <li>04 ПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
                <li>05 ПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
                <li>06 ПУНКТ МЕНЮ</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: И Вам спасибо добрый человек.